# Can Aurora RDS Serverless be restricted to a geography?

Tags: amazon-aurora

I am developing an application on AWS and it has regulatory needs to retain the data in a certain geography. I know that with RDS we can achieve the same. But if we use Aurora Server-less, can we define that my data does not leave the geography in which the Amazon data centre is located.

I have gone through the documentation of AWS. It seems to suggest that the data is geographically distributed to improve latency. But this would mean I do not have control over where the data is. My need is the opposite of it, where I want to restrict it to a certain geo location.

Comment: Hi Shabash, unless you need more clarification, do you mind accepting the answer? Let me know if you need more info here.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora Serverless clusters are similar to Provisioned clusters - they are tied to a region. Provisioned clusters have new features like Global databases which makes the data available in other geographies, but Aurora Serverless does not support those features. Your data in, say, us-east-1 is not leaving that region.